# How to convert string with float to decimal?

Tags: c++, decimal, number-systems

There are many discussions on methods of conversion strings with float to decimal float, but i didn't find solution of my problem in C++ (python, C#, etc. have nice & quick ones). Let me describe algorithm in brief.

Firstly, we enter number system of initial number and enter float number into string variable.

```
int sys = 0;
std::cin >> sys;   //example: 16
string input = ""; 
std::cin >> input; //example: 7ff.12c
```

Then divide **input** into **right** (double) and **left** (int) parts
Then call function **void floatToDec(string input, int sys, char flag)** for both of these parts (flag 'l' means left part flag 'r' meens right part).
To save **result_int** and **result_double** we make them global.

Function:

```
string alf = { '0','1','2', .. , 'x', 'y', 'z' }
int counter = 0; 
int_temp = 0;
for (int i = size(input); i >= 0; i--){
    int index = indexOf(input[i], alf);
    switch (flag) {
        case 'r':
            result_double += index * pow(sys, counter);
            counter--;
            break;
        case 'l':
            int_temp = result_int + index * pow(sys, counter);
            if (int_temp < 0) {
                result_int = 0;
                return 1; // out of integer borders
            }
            result_int = int_temp;
            counter++;
            break;
      }
}
return 0;
```

After executing function for both parts we sum them. into one float. This sum is the result

**PROBLEM**

Integer part of this float can't be more than integer max value (2,147,483,647 in dec) but float can be 2^38-1 as exponent has 8 bits. Same with double, its exponent has 11 bits and value can be 2^52-1. (If i'm not misstaken).

So, how can i solve this issure? May be there is another way to convert?

Comment: split the string on the decimal part and then use `std::stoi`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int getNumber(char c)
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9')
        return c - '0';
    else
        return (c - 'a') + 10;
}

int main()
{
    int sys;
    std::cin >> sys;
    std::string s;
    std::cin >> s;

    long long result_int = 0;
    std::string::size_type i = 0;
    while (s[i] != '.')
        result_int = result_int * sys + getNumber(s[i++]);
    ++i;
    long long result_double = 0;
    while (i < s.size())
        result_double = result_double * sys + getNumber(s[i++]);

    std::cout << result_int << ' ' << result_double << std::endl;
}
```